# Can I use duct tape instead of a draft hood?

Tags: water-heater, vent, duct-tape

I have a small opening between my vent and water heater. Instead of buying a draft hood, is there any harm in using duct tape?[image]

Comment: A draft hood serves a particular purpose, that somebody else may be able to explain, but do not do what you ask, BAD NEWS!!!

Comment: And to further what @Jack says, it isn't duct tape.  You would use exhaust taping.  But don't.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your hot water heater is positively vented (i.e. an exhaust blower), you need a draft hood in order to prevent back pressure in the vent line.  If you connect directly to the hot water heater without a draft hood, you are risking having the pilot light blown out by pressure in the vent (think wind) or letting exhaust gases escape into your house. It's a bit fuzzy in your picture, but it appears that the heater has attachment points for a draft hood. If that is correct, don't omit it in your venting.